# Can GAP compute logarithms?

Tags: gap

I have been using GAP lately and I know how to compute logarithms, but only in some cases by using the function LogInt(n,b).

So for example if $n=5^8$ and $b=5$, then

LogInt($5^8$, $5$)=$8$.

But imagine I want to compute $\log_3(5)=1,46...$. If I put
LogInt($5$, $3$) I get $1$.
Is there any function or package that can give me a better approximation?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not think that GAP is designed for those tasks , it deals mainly with groups. PARI/GP fits far better for such calcaultions.

Comment: Have a look at the section on floats in the [documentation](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap19_mj.html#X81AA901181CA568F). While it's definitely not GAP's strong suit, it can do some operations on floating-point numbers (IIRC, it wasn't always so).

Comment: the natural log command in GAP is just `Log`, and you can compute logs in other bases using that

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have found, GAP's standard mathematical operations for Floats ([Link to documentation](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap19.html)) only includes:

- Log();    Natural logarithm
- Log2();   Logarithm base 2
- Log10();  Logarithm base 10
- Log1p();  Logarithm base ??

Besides that i didn't found any libaries for other logarithms